# How to tell whether bluetooth adapter supports bluetooth LE (4.0)?

Tags: linux, sockets, bluetooth

I have two Bluetooth adapters, an old internal adapter and a new Bluetooth 4.0 adapter.

I am writing an application that uses a `socket(PF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_SEQPACKET, BTPROTO_L2CAP)` to connect to a Bluetooth LE device on Linux. When I call `connect()` with a `sockaddr_l2 {.l2_family = AF_BLUETOOTH, .l2_bdaddr = {...}, .l2_cid = L2CAP_CID_ATT, .l2_bdaddr_type = BRADDR_LE_PUBLIC}`, connect fails with errno=0x38000000=939524096 Unknown error, because Linux arbitrarily chooses the old adapter that only supports Bluetooth 2.1, not Bluetooth 4.0. The solution is to bind the socket to the bd_addr of the adapter that supports Bluetooth 4.0.

Question: How to tell which adapter is the Bluetooth 4.0 adapter? hciconfig does not tell which one is the one to use; they both say BR/EDR and not LE.

```
$ hciconfig
hci1:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:25:00:F6:97:F0  ACL MTU: 1021:5  SCO MTU: 64:1
    UP RUNNING PSCAN 
    RX bytes:1074 acl:0 sco:0 events:56 errors:0
    TX bytes:1462 acl:0 sco:0 commands:56 errors:0

hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:02:72:D6:A0:BF  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
    UP RUNNING PSCAN 
    RX bytes:146505 acl:328 sco:0 events:4189 errors:0
    TX bytes:6213 acl:215 sco:0 commands:83 errors:0
$ modinfo bluetooth | grep ^version:
version:        2.17
$ modinfo btusb | grep ^version:
version:        0.6
$ lsb_release --description
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
$ uname --kernel-release
3.13.0-40-generic
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try: `hciconfig hci[0|1] version`

Comment: For those confused by the syntax in this answer: `hciconfig hci0 version` OR `hciconfig hci1 version`. But if you read `man hciconfig` you'll see: `If hciX is not given, hciconfig prints name and basic information about all the Bluetooth devices installed in the system.` In other words: `hciconfig` will do; only actual devices will be listed.

Answer (score 13):

To answer your question there is `btmgmt info` which will list the HCI version (on the same line as `addr`), you will have to look into [Host Controller Interface Assigned numbers](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/host-controller-interface) for the meaning of the numbers, version 6 below mean Bluetooth 4.0.

```
# btmgmt info
hci0:   Primary controller
addr 5C:F3:70:XX:XX:XX version 6 manufacturer 15 class 0x1c010c
supported settings: powered connectable fast-connectable discoverable bondable link-security ssp br/edr hs le advertising secure-conn debug-keys privacy configuration static-addr 
current settings: powered bondable ssp br/edr le secure-conn 
name BlueZ 5.47
short name
```

If you need to know if the adapter support LE, you will have to look for `le` in `Supported settings:` because LE is not mandatory in bluetooth 4.0/4.1.

Comment: Super-useful answer +1. Wonder why no `man page` for this? What would be x-cool would be an app that translated the `btmgmt` info into something directly readable.

Comment: Thank you for letting us know that LE is not mandatory in Bluetooth 4.0+.

Comment: This is the only way to do it on bluez>=5.44, since they removed `hcitool` from that release by default (although I noticed that Ubuntu has continued to include it for backwards-compatibility).